Constructing the voltage as a function of time for a circuit with a capacitor and resistor under a current source
I have a circuit as shown in the image.
I want to derive the formula for the voltage V(t) as a function of time; when a constant current source is applied.


What do you know how to do? I mean, you have a current source and only two devices there to sink it. The sum of their currents will be equal to the current source. Do you know how to compute the current in a capacitor? You need to write about what you already know.

Is this homework?

Convert the current source and resistor to the Thevenin equivalent. Then you will have the familiar RC charged by a voltage source.
Most people will then recognize that this is an exponential that starts at zero and ends at Vf, where Vf = Is*R (because of the source transformation).
Or, you can write the differential equation solve it. I could when I was in college, I can't anymore without help. Khan has a good tutorial.
https://www.khanacademy.org/science/electrical-engineering/ee-circuit-analysis-topic/ee-natural-and-forced-response/a/ee-rc-step-response#:~:text=The%20method%20for%20solving%20a%20circuit%20driven%20by,Use%20the%20initial%20conditions%20to%20resolve%20any%20constants.
